# Loop through rows to get column data using selenium and python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, multiple-columns, rows

I'm trying to use Python 3.6 and Selenium to grab data form a table. One of the tables I'm trying to grab from has multiple rows. So, I want to get column 9 from each row.

I searched around on this site and found some code that I was able to adapt to almost work.

```
table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_mid_rptItems_ctl00_gvItems')
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")  
    for col in cols:
        print (cols[8].text)
```

It spits out the correct data from the column I want, but the problem I'm having is that it loops through each row 16 times, which is the number of columns in the table, and prints each data point 16 times.

I tried to adapt the code above to just spit out each column 1 time by removing the "for col" loop

```
table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_mid_rptItems_ctl00_gvItems')
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    print (cols[8].text)
```

But, this gives the the error "Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Documents\PleaseTest_R1.py", line 91, in 
print (cols[8].text)
IndexError: list index out of range

Any ideas on how I can get this loop to work?
Thanks so much for the help! :-)

Comment: If you use WATIR(Selenium wrapper made by Ruby), you don't have to face these problems because it gives you the nice syntax like `b.table.rows.each`. So the solution to your problem is, Use JavaScript if you are working in Chrome or Mozilla. If you are working in IE, then JavaScript is also not a solution

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would love to be able to do the whole thing in Python if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use Javascript, Execute this JavaScript via your python program, it will work.

Systax to take content from the cell,

```
document.getElementId("tableid").rows[3].cells[4].innerHTML
```

And you can get row count by

```
document.getElementId("tableid").rows.length
```